# Why is the Elevation Z Data not showing in the bottom tool bar along side the coordinate data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, elevation, toolbar

I have been using Globalmapper for around 10 years and just recently started exploring the capabilities of QGIS to compare if QGIS has any major advantages.

Mostly our work is with DEM and LiDAR Point cloud data sets for terrain volume change calculations.

It is early days yet, but first issue I noted is there is now elevation data showing on mouse hover on the bottom tool bar. Is there anyway to add this?
[image]
If searched online for over an hour but nothing comes up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In the currently released versions of QGIS (through 3.24), this is not available.

To show elevation in such a way, you have to declare one raster as representing terrain. Currently QGIS does not support that in the map canvas, i.e. rasters can be rendered (including colour, or post-processing such as contours or hillshade) but you can't specify that one raster represents elevation specifically. You can do that in a 3D map view, but that is separate from the 2D map canvas.

Already in the current (3.25) development masters, a **significant rework of terrain treatment is underway**, to be released in version **3.26**. The principal feature is a pretty flexible elevation profile tool, but it also adds project-wide unified support for elevation/terrains, including the specification that a specific raster defines terrain. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/246. While I don't believe displaying elevation in the bottom bar, alongside coordinates, as you move around on the canvas is directly included, it is a pretty natural evolution to be added with this as its basis.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can use the **Identify** tool. Select your DEM raster from the layer tree, keep the Identify dock open, and click anywhere in the canvas for the elevation of the point you just clicked to be displayed. If important, you could also create a python script that displays elevation (i.e. probes a specific raster, the DEM, for its value at current point) and assign it to an unused keyboard shortcut.

BTW I did a quick scan of QGIS plugins and don't think there is one which does exactly what you want in existence already. Happy to be corrected!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this is very helpful.  And yes I also could not find any plugins to do this as well.  I did see a conversation from 2015 discussing exactly this and for showing data on mouse hover. But thats all I found.   I will do as you suggest and try the Identify tool for now.   So far I found the 3D viewer not very good compared to GM which also has a lot of functions within the viewer.  A few other items I found clunky were hill shaders and contours. I wont be to hard though, it might just be my lack of expertise with those.

Comment: @Aerial-Craft.Com, I'm sure you know this, but each software has its strengths. I know a number of ag/industry people who like Globalmapper exactly because of its ease of use for handing vector/spatial data from multiple sources in a single xy and z framework. Arguably, QGIS is particularly strong (and stronger than GM) for making beautiful maps, data format flexibility, and for integration with open source geospatial tools like Grass and SAGA. And ArcGIS has undeniable strength with disseminating GIS to the public. Each is strong enough to do OK on other stuff, just not as seamless.